# How to search arabic words in solr

Tags: search, solr, arabic-support

In my solr schema.xml I defined product arabic name field as below

```xml
<field name="productNameArabic" type="text_ar" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <fieldType name="text_ar" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer> 
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_ar.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.ArabicNormalizationFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ArabicStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

In solr search I want to search with product name using Arabic letters. While searching, Arabic user can feel little default to search some product name. Because some characters need to mention while searching.

Ex: إ أ آ

In the above mentioned characters, user can get combination of shift key. Usually if Arabic people will mention “ ا “  character and will get the below combined words.

Ex: إبرا

In my solr schema.xml I defined product arabic name field as below

Comment: so, what's your problem? did you get exception or something?

Comment: My problem is if press “ ا “ character,  solr search matching this characters words only. I want if I press “ ا “ character solr should search إ أ آ  combined character words as well. 
 There is no exception

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve desired functionality by adding `ASCIIFoldingFilter`, this filter is able to remove accents from different languages, to make them similar in index time.

```
<fieldType name="arabic" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
            <analyzer>
                <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_ar.txt" />
                <filter class="solr.ArabicNormalizationFilterFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.ArabicStemFilterFactory"/>
            </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Some more information about this filter - [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-ASCIIFoldingFilter). Working code example - [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MysterionRise/information-retrieval-adventure/master/lucene5/src/main/scala/org/mystic/SearchArabicWords.scala)

Comment: thanks for investigation our problem,I tried with above example,but it's not working as we expected result.. Please refer the document I explained Arabic search expected result. Using this link please download the document https://www.sendspace.com/file/3d4ori

Comment: @Mohan,what's the output there and the expected one?

Comment: Please refer the document(download from https://sendspace.com/file/3d4ori this rul)... In that document Table 1 I mentioned index values and expected result. Ex: Take case : 1 if enter المؤسسة التجارية this i should get المؤسسة التجارية العمانية  this result. but right now I am not able to get the result.